# What are the ways to block all BitTorrent clients from accessing my router?

Tags: firewalls, wifi, router, bittorrent

What are all the values need to be entered in the source and destination IP address and Subnet mask in order to block the bit torrent file exchange.. i.e. blocking torrenting

My router's filtering webpage asks for:

Source IP adress:

Subnet mask:

Port number:

Destination IP adress:

Subnet mask:

Port number:

I have no idea what to enter in subnet mask.

I know that the Port number to block BT is 1024-65538
What are all the other vales I should enter.
Here's the screenshot of the router page:
[image: Screenshot of the Router's Filter Page]

Answer (score 3):

Bittorrent trackers often operate on the same port 80 that web servers do, and data transfers don't operate on a fixed port.  Port blocking isn't an effective way to block Bittorrent traffic, rather, your router needs to support [deep packet inspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_packet_inspection) to identify and block the transfers.

Consumer-grade routers almost never support deep packet inspection.